# Where should boot loader be installed?

Tags: bootloader

So while installing Ubuntu MATE 17.04 Grub failed to install and I need to choose where to install the boot loader. The way I see it I have 3 places where I can place it: sda (my supposed ssd but where grub couldn't install) sdb which is where ubuntu is located but not where windows is installed, or sdb1 which is labeled windows 10.  Basically W10 is installed on my ssd while Ubuntu is on my regular hard drive and I am unsure of where to install the bootloader

Answer (score 1):

If it's not possible to install grub at `/dev/sda` then install it on `/dev/sdb`.

The thing is, at least one of your hard drives should have a boot loader on its boot sector, then in your BIOS set that hard drive as your primary hard disk.

When you turn on your computer, BIOS looks for the first sector on your primary hard drive, if it was able to locate an specific Hex code on that sector, it means a boot loader lives on that and BIOS will run it.

Comment: So if I install the bootloader to my ubuntu installation,will I still be able to choose to boot to windows from grub since it is on a separate hard drive?

Comment: Yes, however make sure grub is aware of windows by running : `sudo update-grub`